# How to pass multiple files to zip in a single command using 7 zip?

Tags: 7-zip

I have one folder which will contain below mentioned files:

```
destiny.txt
destiny1.txt
destiny2.txt
destiny3.txt
destiny4.txt
destiny5.txt
destiny6.txt
destiny7.txt
```

Out of which destiny1.txt, destiny4.txt, destiny6.txt are from batch1.

I am using `7zip` to zip the files.

Can I pass these 3 files in a single step to create `DestinyTest.zip`?

Is it possible?

Comment: [List file](http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm)

Answer (score 29):

> Can I pass these 3 files in a single step to create `DestinyTest.zip`?

You can use the command line version of 7zip which is `7z`.

From a command line:

```
7z a -tzip DestinyTest.zip destiny1.txt destiny4.txt destiny6.txt
```

- `a` - Adds files to archive.
- `-tzip` - Specifies the type of archive (we are creating a `zip` archive).

---

#### Further reading

- [7zip Command Line Syntax](http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm)
- [7zip Command Line Switches](http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/index.htm)
- [7zip Command Line Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Answer (score 9):

If you have a file listing the files to make the zip, eg

create a list of files to archive, one on each line.  This is an @-list, from DOS days, a number of proggies will do this for each line.

You can create such a file with `dir /b destin*.* > zipme.lst`, and then remove lines in a ascii editor (notepad or edit).

> type zipme.lst
>   destiny1.txt
>   destiny4.txt
>   destiny6.txt
>    7za a -tzip DestinyTest.zip @zipme.lst

This will find zipme.lst, and add all the files listed in it.  It can be longer than the command-line, and you have some control over it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and wanted to do it with a **batch script**. Here is how:

In the example below, the script looks for all .csv files starting with "cell_cfg" and "slave_cfg", collects them, and zips them in one file called 'cfg.7z' stored in a subdirectory called 'zip':

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
mkdir zip
ECHO collecting filenames...
set filenames="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "zip/cfg.7z
FOR %%i IN (cell_cfg*.csv) DO (
    ECHO "%%i" | FIND /I "zip_cfg.bat" 1>NUL) || (
        SET filenames=!filenames!" "%%i
    )
)
FOR %%i IN (slave_cfg*.csv) DO (
    ECHO "%%i" | FIND /I "zip_cfg.bat" 1>NUL) || (
        SET filenames=!filenames!" "%%i
    )
)
set filenames=%filenames%"
%filenames%
```

(Adjust the path of your 7z.exe and files/folder names. If you want .zip instead of .7z, rename the lines:

```
set filenames="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "zip/cfg.7z
```

into

```
set filenames="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "zip/cfg.zip
```

)

I saved it as 'zip_cfg.bat' and place it in the folder with the files I want to zip. Then I can call it in the command line: first, navigate to the folder with the files, then just call:

```
zip_cfg.bat
```

In case you want to zip all files in the folder ("*"), the 'FIND /I "zip_cfg.bat" 1>NUL' part stops the script from zipping the batch file itself.

Hope this helps someone... :)